# NetSuite's SuiteCommerce Advance: Customize Multi Language With Single Domain(Without Hosts)?

Tags: subdomain, netsuite, suitecommerce

In SuiteCommerce Advance Vision release by default behavior to setup multi language is to add multiple domain under Setup-->Configuration-->Multi Domain Tab--> Hosts

Once you setup this you can able to see drop down in your web store which will have domain and language associate with that domain. We have already implemented this feature.

But, SCA also has feature to setup multi language with 'lang' parameter which will automatically change language withing single domain like below

```
We did this already-->(With multiple domain)
https://www.en.scasite.com/
https://www.fr.scasite.com/


We want below setup-->

https://www.scasite.com/?lang=en_US
https://www.scasite.com/?lang=fr_FR
```

So, Can any one have idea how we can pass language param in url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right SCA out of the box don't have this feature, but yes you can send 'lang' param in url and can able to change your language.

**Remember if you are uding SCA vision release, do not add any language hosts in configuration under setup tab**

To pass 'lang' param i.e www.domain.com/lang=it_IT etc

Override the Host selector file in your custom module to do this, you need to create below two files under global view

1.Modules/custom/GlobalViews@1.0.0/JavaScript/GlobalViews.HostSelector.View.js
Copy & paste below code in setLanguage: function (e){}

```
,   setLanguage: function (e)
    {
                var language_code = jQuery(e.target).val()
            ,   selected_language = _.find(SC.ENVIRONMENT.availableLanguages, function (language)
                {
                    return language.locale === language_code;

                });

        // We use the param **"cur"** to pass this to the ssp environment
        var current_search = Utils.parseUrlOptions(window.location.search);

        // if we are in a facet result we will remove all facets and navigate to the default search
        // TODO REVIEW THIS
        if (window.location.hash !== '' && _.values(SC._applications)[0].getLayout().currentView instanceof BrowseView)
        {
            window.location.hash = Configuration.defaultSearchUrl || '';
        }
        current_search.lang = selected_language.locale;

        window.location.search = _.reduce(current_search, function (memo, val, name)
        {
            return val ? memo + name + '=' + val + '&' : memo;
        }, '?');

    }
```

Use below code in getContext() to return some data to handlbar view

```
var available_languages = _.map(SC.ENVIRONMENT.availableLanguages, function(language)
        {
            // @class GlobalViews.CurrencySelector.View.Context.Currency
            return {
                // @property {String} code
                code: language.locale
                // @property {String} internalId
            ,   internalId: language.internalid
                // @property {String} isDefault
            ,   isDefault: language.isdefault
                // @property {String} symbol
            ,   symbol: language.languagename
                // @property {String} displayName
            ,   displayName: language.locale|| language.locale

            , isSelected: SC.ENVIRONMENT.currentLanguage.locale === language.locale

            };
        });

        // @class GlobalViews.CurrencySelector.View.Context
        return {
            // @property {Boolean} showCurrencySelector
            showLanguageSelector: !!(SC.ENVIRONMENT.availableLanguages && SC.ENVIRONMENT.availableLanguages.length > 1)
            // @property {Array<GlobalViews.CurrencySelector.View.Context.Currency>} availableCurrencies
        ,    availableLanguages: available_languages || []
            // @property {String} currentCurrencyCode
            // @property {String} currentCurrencySymbol
        ,   currentLanguageSymbol: SC.getSessionInfo('language').languagename
        };
    }
```

2. Copy & Paste Below code in below file 
   Modules/custom/GlobalViews@1.0.0/Templates/global_views_host_selector.tpl

```html
    {{#if showLanguageSelector}}
     <div class="global-views-currency-selector">
      <span class="global-views-host-selector-addon">
       {{currentLanguageSymbol}}
      </span>
      <select data-toggle="currency-selector" class="global-views-currency-selector-select">
       {{#each availableLanguages}}
        <option value="{{code}}" {{#if isSelected}}selected{{/if}}>
         {{symbol}}
        </option>
       {{/each}}
      </select>
     </div>
    {{/if}}
```

3. Done!! Now you can see 'lang' param is being added into url

Let me know if you want more help on this.

Comment: This is Awesome it help me a lot, one query is do I need o remove hosts from configuration?

Comment: Yes, You must need to remove domain if you have under configuration